# Get Handler Type Automatically

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

```
var myassembly = BuildAssembly(new System.IO.StreamReader("Code.txt").ReadToEnd());

                Type tip = myassembly.GetType("Form1");
                var obje = Activator.CreateInstance(tip);


                var obj = treeView1;
                string eventName = "NodeMouseClick";

                var evt = obj.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);



                TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler myCode =(s,k)=>
                {
                    tip.InvokeMember("Node",

                               BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance |        BindingFlags.Public,

                               null, obje ,new object[]{s,k});

                };
                evt.AddEventHandler(obj, myCode);
```

I can Add a event handler the control with this code.But if I want to a button click event I have to use EventHanler.I want to get Handler type automatically like if event type is
key down add KeyDownEventHanler How can I make this?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create delegate of any type with Delegate.CreateDelegate(...) method. Also creating anonymous method that use InvokeMember to invoke "Node" method is not neccessary as long as parameters of your "Node" method are assign-compatible with delegate's parameters and thus no special conversion of parameters is needed. Then instead of

```
TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler myCode =(s,k)=>
{
    tip.InvokeMember("Node",
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
        null,
        obje,
        new object[]{s,k});
};
```

just create delegate to "Node" method, that is of the same type that event expects:

```
MethodInfo NodeMethod = tip.GetMethod("Node", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
Delegate myCode = Delegate.CreateDelegate(evt.EventHandlerType, obje, NodeMethod);
```